# What JVM runtime data area are included in ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I was trying to get the memory consumption of some code snippets. After some search, I realized that `ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)` can be used to achieve this. So I tested this method with the following code:

```
    ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = (ThreadMXBean) ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
//      new Long(0);
    long beforeMemUsage = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(id);
    long afterMemUsage = 0;

    {
        // put the code you want to measure here
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Long(i);
        }
    }

    afterMemUsage = threadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(id);
    System.out.println(afterMemUsage - beforeMemUsage);
```

I run this code with different iteration times in for loop (0, 1, 10, 20, and 30). And the result as follows:

```
0 Long: 48 bytes
1 Long: 456 bytes
10 Long:    672 bytes
20 Long:    912 bytes
30 Long:    1152 bytes
```

The differences between 1 and 10, 10 and 20, as well as 20 and 30 are easy to explain, because the size of Long object is 24 bytes. But I was confused by the huge difference between 0 and 1.
Actually, I guessed this is caused by the class loading. So I uncommented the 3rd line code and the result as follows:

```
0 Long: 48 bytes
1 Long: 72 bytes
10 Long:    288 bytes
20 Long:    528 bytes
30 Long:    768 bytes
```

It seems that my guess is confirmed by the result. However, in my opinion, the information of class structure is stored in Method Area, which is not a part of heap memory. As the Javadoc of [ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes-long-) indicates, it returns `the total amount of memory allocated in heap memory`. Have I missed something?

The tested JVM version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first invocation of `new Long(0)` causes the resolution of the constant pool entry referenced by `new` bytecode. While resolving `CONSTANT_Class_info` for the first time, JVM loads the referenced class - `java.lang.Long`.

[`ClassLoader.loadClass`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/78d2004f65eb/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#l395) is implemented in Java, and it can certainly allocate Java objects. For instance, [`getClassLoadingLock`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/78d2004f65eb/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#l453) method creates a new lock object and a new entry in `parallelLockMap`:

```
    protected Object getClassLoadingLock(String className) {
        Object lock = this;
        if (parallelLockMap != null) {
            Object newLock = new Object();
            lock = parallelLockMap.putIfAbsent(className, newLock);
            if (lock == null) {
                lock = newLock;
            }
        }
        return lock;
    }
```

Also, when doing a class name lookup in the system dictionary, JVM creates a new String object.

I used [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) to record all heap allocations JVM does when loading `java.lang.Long` class. Here is the clickable interactive Flame Graph:

[image: Allocation Flame Graph]

The graph includes 13 samples - one per each allocated object. The type of an allocated object is not shown, but it can be easily guessed from the context (stack trace).

- Green color denotes Java stack trace;
- Yellow means VM stack trace.

Note that each `java_lang_String::basic_create()` (and similar) allocates two objects: an instance of `java.lang.String` and its backing `char[]` array.

The graph is produced by the following test program:

```
import one.profiler.AsyncProfiler;

public class ProfileHeapAlloc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AsyncProfiler profiler = AsyncProfiler.getInstance();

        // Dry run to skip allocations caused by AsyncProfiler initialization
        profiler.start("_ZN13SharedRuntime19dtrace_object_allocEP7oopDesci", 0);
        profiler.stop();

        // Real profiling session
        profiler.start("_ZN13SharedRuntime19dtrace_object_allocEP7oopDesci", 0);

        new Long(0);

        profiler.stop();
        profiler.execute("file=alloc.svg");
    }
}
```

How to run:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/async-profiler -XX:+DTraceAllocProbes ProfileHeapAlloc
```

Here `_ZN13SharedRuntime19dtrace_object_allocEP7oopDesci` is the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for `SharedRuntime::dtrace_object_alloc()` function, which is called by JVM for every heap allocation whenever `DTraceAllocProbes` flag is on.

Comment: Great explanation! I have reproduced the flame graph at my laptop. But I can't see there are 13 Java objects were allocated. Can you give more explanation about this? Thanks!

Comment: Besides, what does the `_ZN13SharedRuntime19dtrace_object_allocEP7oopDesci` mean?